# in python, what is the best way to iterate without using for or while loops to update serial number column after deleting few rows?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner in python and I want to create a to do application (no GUI). i created a python list () with certain number of records with a "Serial Number" column. When I delete one or more records, i want to update the serial numbers only from the first deleted row until end. what is the best way to do this without using for or while loops? Right now I'm updating row number of all the records which I don't like.
Sample data is below:

```py
header = ["Task Id", "Task", "Description", "Due Date", "Created Date", "Status", "Completed Date", "Task Remarks"]
task = [
    [1, "buy", "buy food", "01/01/2023", "30/11/2022", "Completed", "25/12/2022"],
    [2, "sell", "sell in OLX", "25/12/2022", "10/12/2022", "To be completed", "", "No buyer came up yet"],
    [3, "travel", "book flight tickets", "01/02/2023", "05/12/2022"],
    [4, "workout", "register at a gym", "02/01/2023", "25/12/2022", "Completed", "31/12/2022"],
    [5, "gardening", "buy new plants and pots", "10/01/2023", "20/12/2022", "to be completed", "No good nurseries nearby"],
    [6, "buy books", "visit a shopping mall or browse online for new good books", "15/02/2023", "05/12/2022"]
]
```

my delete function is

```py
def delete_task():
    print()
    task_id = int(input("Enter task to be deleted: "))
    if task_id > len(task) or task_id <= 0:
        print("Provided task id is valid. Retry.")
        delete_task()
    elif task_id <= len(task) and task_id > 0:
        id_index = task_id - 1
        print(f"Task deleted: {task[id_index]}")
        task.pop(id_index)
    else:
        print("Provided task id is valid. Retry.")
        delete_task()
    for i in range(len(task)):
        task[i][0] = i + 1
    print()
    print(f"Total tasks available: {len(task)}")
    print()
    show_tasks() # displays the available tasks
```

I tried to use index of the deleted row and iterated from that row number until end using for loop. But, I  ended up getting same row numbers for the deleted row and immediate next row.

Comment: Why bother with changing that id column ? In databases, that's called a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) and the main advantage is that the id always points to the same record. So even if you remove record 3, then record 4 is still pointing to workout, and references to 4 don't need to change.

Comment: let's say tasks `1` and `2` has been deleted, do you need to reindex the `task` list so it starts with index `1` ?

Comment: I think any way that doesn't use a loop is just going to be more complicated for no reason. Why are you against using loops for this?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes. I need to reindex the list. This task index is something that was not auto assigned. I have created this index along with every task addition in my code. So everytime any task is deleted, I need to allot new task id depending upon how many tasks were deleted.

Comment: @DeanJohnson, Yes, you're right. It does complicate the situation but I just wanted to know if something of that sort was available, which I can use in future projects when needed to scale.

Comment: @CrossDeLainem, are you allowed to use additional libraries/packages ?

Comment: I can't think of anything better than iterating through and updating everything. Is the concern that these indexes are used in many other places to access some kind of shared data structure? If so, maybe you have a mapping from virtual to real index. Virtual indices are used throughout the app and never change. When a lookup is done with the virtual index, it is mapped to a real index. When a deletion is done, you would need to update the mapping (since real indices changed), but that would transparently "update" all usages of the virtual indexes throughout the app.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes, libraries and packages are most welcome. the thing is being beginner i don't have much knowledge of most of them.